# SSRS 2008 Time format

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I am trying to format a string as a hour in a reporting services project. I am trying to find the difference between the hour of a given date (date1) and 16:30 (which marks the end of a working day). Simply put: 16:30 - hour  I am using the DateDiff formula below:

```
= DateDiff(Dateinterval.Hour, Hour("16:30"), Hour(Fields!Date1.Value))
```

However, the formula above throws an error when I am previewing the report. Can someone help me with getting to the correct formula??

Comment: Whats the erroe syntax??

Comment: SSRS uses syntax different from SQL Server for DateDiff, look it up

Comment: The 2nd and third parameters need to be Date/DateTime data types.  So for the 2nd param, that needs to be a full date, and just don't cast the 3rd param as an HOUR.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have mentioned, you need to be comparing two DateTimes in a `DateDiff` expression.

To do this, you need the first date, i.e. your **16:30** time, to be based on the second date. One way of doing this is something like:

```
=DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour
    , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
    , Fields!Date1.Value)
```

Based on this, you can easily enhance it to only return differences for the differences for dates with time > **16:30**:

```
=IIf(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour
        , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
        , Fields!Date1.Value) > 0
    , DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour
        , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
        , Fields!Date1.Value)
    , 0)
```

You can even format the difference in minutes as **HH:mm**:

```
=CStr(CInt(IIf(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
        , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
        , Fields!Date1.Value) > 0
    , DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
        , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
        , Fields!Date1.Value)
    , 0) / 60))
    & ":"
    & CStr(IIf(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
            , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
            , Fields!Date1.Value) > 0
        , DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute
            , CDate(Format(Fields!Date1.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "T16:30:00")
            , Fields!Date1.Value)
        , 0) mod 60)
```

These last two expressions could be greatly simplified with a **Calculated Field** to work out the time difference but this answer is long enough already.

You can see this is working for me:

[image]

Comment: Did this answer help at all?